# Password doesn't work for desktop but does for terminal

Tags: 14.04, password, vmware, guest-os

I'm a Linux newbie, I'm doing quite well starting to get my head around it. But I've run into a problem. I don't plan to use the GUI much but here's the problem:
My root account password works in terminal mode but when i switch to startx the same password for the same account doesn't work. after entering it, the screen flickers to a black screen then the original screen reappears asking for the password.

Oh and its a Guest on a VMware Hypervisor

Any ideas? Cheers

Comment: Have you checked http://askubuntu.com/questions/223501/ubuntu-gets-stuck-in-a-login-loop ?

Comment: It sounds exactly like my problem, thanks. I'll have a look and then update.

Comment: I've tried everything in the other article, but still doing the same thing. I was going to uninstall ubuntu-desktop and try again.
Does apt-get purge ubuntu-desktop completely remove it? And like Windows does it need a reboot after doing so? Thanks again

Comment: Before that, try to create a new user and see if the graphic login works for it. `apt-get purge` will not touch the home directories --- so if the problem is there it will not solve anything.

Comment: The simplest answers are always the best! created a new user and it worked. That will sort my problem for now. Cheers

Comment: I added an answer to the above linked question suggesting this: http://askubuntu.com/a/553812/16395 --- please upvote it if it was useful.